# Mongoose Model functions not being recognized

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, ecmascript-6

I have setup an NodeJS/Express webserver, and am attempting to write data into a DB that has already been connected. I am using MongoDB with Mongoose. Here is a test Schema I wrote to save into the database, based off of a Github commit.

```
// Commit.js
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const CommitSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  message: {
    required: true,
    type: String
  },
  url: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  author: {
    type: Object,
    required: true,
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    date: {
      type: Date,
      required: true
    }
  }
});

const CommitModel = mongoose.model("Commit", CommitSchema);

export default CommitModel;
```

I have imported this into a file that counts how many of these Commit documents there are in the DB.

```
//lib.js
import Commit from "./Commit";

const test = async () => {
  console.log(await Commit.find());
}
test();
```

This returns the error: `_Commit__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.default.find is not a function`.
I don't understand what I am doing wrong. Why does it not see the Commit model as valid?

Comment: are you sure that is the right path `"./Commit"`?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Somehow, through the rest of the React app, that code was being run through the App.js react file. I am not sure why. I moved the code referencing `Commit.find()` into a server route and called it through axios, and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mongoose via npm install mongoose, and see the docs [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html)